# Twitter plot created time

Tags: r, twitter, plot

I'm trying to plot the created time of twitters. I can extract the created time with the following code:

```
tweets <- searchTwitter('weather', n=100,lang='en')
t <- twListToDF(tweets)
s <- t[, c("created")]
```

The time format I get is something like: 2017-02-25 18:52:06 UTC

Trying to plot it with plot(s) provides just a list of dots. I'm not sure if it is due to the date/time format.

I want to create a barchart that each bar represents the count of tweets on an hourly period. The x axis would represent time and the y axis the number of tweets.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

One approach that I've used uses the 'lubridate' package, which is available on CRAN.

`library(lubridate)
date(now())
hour(now())`

You would replace `now()` with your vector `s`. If your `s` vector has the class POSIXct, I believe that this will work. There might be alternative solutions that involve the lubridate R package, too. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me started on what I need